# R programming: Find all the factors from Data Frame

Tags: r

I am trying to get the class type of the columns of a data frame. What I am doing is:

```
sapply(mydata,class)
```

But now, I want to find only those column names which are factor. I tried the following:

```
sapply(data,is.factor)
```

But it gives me:

```
ResponseFlag            Gender           Marital        OccupInput
 False                   True             True            False
```

How can I separate column names which are factor?

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Many ways. One: `names(grep("factor", sapply(data, class), value=TRUE))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
Filter(is.factor, mydata)
```

**names only** If you just want the names:

```
names(Filter(is.factor, mydata))
```

or

```
names(iris)[ sapply(iris, is.factor) ]
```

**dplyr** These can alternately be expressed using dplyr like this:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% Filter(f = is.factor)

mydata %>% Filter(f = is.factor) %>% names

mydata %>% summarise_each(funs(is.factor)) %>% unlist %>% .[.] %>% names
```

Comment: Note to OP: this returns a data frame.

Comment: @ hrbrmstr, i can extract the colnames