# Is there a R function to list down the only variables that is a factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. I need to list down the variables that are only factor. I have a code that I have assigned to res. But I am not able to execute it

```
 > df
   x y g  a
 1 a 2 1  df
 2 a 3 2  fg
 3 b 4 1  gf
 4 b 5 2  fd

for(i in colnames(df))
{
while (class(df[,i])=="factor") {
res <- i
break
}}
```

Expected output is

```
res
"x","a"
```

Comment: Thanks. But can do I select only a variable name, The link only has logical output that is true or false

Comment: [R programming: Find all the factors from Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484938/r-programming-find-all-the-factors-from-data-frame)

Comment: I tried with this fd <- sapply(names(df), is.factor) but did not get

Comment: The link provided above includes : `names(Filter(is.factor, df))` . Have a look at twice please.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df=read.table(text = "
    x y g  a
    a 2 1  df
    a 3 2  fg
    b 4 1  gf
    b 5 2  fd",header=T,stringsAsFactors = T)


colnames(df)[sapply(df,is.factor)]
```